# Querying for new and changed documents in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint

We need to query SharePoint for new and changed documents.  The 'Write' property gives the modified timestamp from inside the document metadata (i.e. inside the document properties), not the time the document was added to SharePoint.

I've tried this query:

```
and(IsDocument:true, write:range(2018-02-16, max) )
```

but the write time is based on the date embedded inside the document (not the date the document was added to SharePoint).

Does anyone have any guidance they can share?

---

Update with more test results:

Digging into the properties, I think that the DiscoveredTime property might be what I'm looking for.  This documentation (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219630.aspx) says that the DiscoveredTime property isn't searchable, but I am able to search using this:

```
and(IsDocument:true, DiscoveredTime:range(2018-02-16, max) )
```

I can't find anywhere that explains what DiscoveredTime actually is, but it seems to correlate with when the document was added to SP.

Comment: can you share some code that you are using to do your current operations ?

Comment: ok - I added the FQL queries that I've tried...